# В чем может быть проблема, что LiveData не возвращает результат?

Tags: android, kotlin, livedata

В целом достаточно простое View у меня 2 поля одно с email другое с номером телефона. Мне нужно сделать валидацию одного и другого и если все в порядке то разблокировать кнопку на экране. Вот такой код у меня

```
@HiltViewModel
class CreateAccountEnterEmailViewModel @Inject constructor(
    appData: AppData,
) : ViewModel() {
    private var email by mutableStateOf("")
    private var phoneNumber by mutableStateOf("")
    private var _isPhoneNumberFieldVisibleState: MutableStateFlow<Boolean> = MutableStateFlow(appData.isPhoneNumberRequiredForRegistrationParam.orDef())
    val isPhoneNumberFieldVisible: LiveData<Boolean> = _isPhoneNumberFieldVisibleState.asLiveData()

    class PairMediatorLiveData<F, S>(firstLiveData: LiveData<F>, secondLiveData: LiveData<S>) : MediatorLiveData<Pair<F?, S?>>() {
        init {
            addSource(firstLiveData) { firstLiveDataValue: F -> value = firstLiveDataValue to secondLiveData.value }
            addSource(secondLiveData) { secondLiveDataValue: S -> value = firstLiveData.value to secondLiveDataValue }
        }
    }

    private val isEmailValid: LiveData<Boolean> =
        snapshotFlow { email }
        .map { validateEmail(email = it) }
        .asLiveData()

    private val isPhoneValid: LiveData<Boolean> =
        snapshotFlow { phoneNumber }
            .map { validatePhone(phone = it) }
            .asLiveData()

    val isContinueBtnEnabled: LiveData<Boolean> = PairMediatorLiveData(isEmailValid, isPhoneValid)
        .switchMap {
            return@switchMap liveData {
                emit(it.first ?: false && it.second ?: false)
            }
        }

    fun updateEmail(email: String) {
        this.email = email
    }

    fun updatePhoneNumber(phoneNumber: String) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
    }
```

То есть идея такая юзер делает update на email или phoneNumber этот апдейт подхватывается медиатором который выдает нужный стейт в зависимости от того пройдена валидация или нет.

Но почему то я вижу, что ничего не идет дальше чем вызов `updateEmail` или `updatePhoneNumber` метода. Что делаю не так?

P.S. Естественно есть подписка в view на `isContinueBtnEnabled`

Comment: А зачем тут намешан и compose и livedata, может что-то одно или чистый flow?

Comment: snapshotFlow точно видит изменения полей? В доке некий метод есть Snapshot.withMutableSnapshot в лямде которого меняю поля

Comment: @IR42 нет snapshot не видит изменения полей, не понятно почему и соответственно ничего не тригается в `MediatorLiveData`

Comment: @IR42 тут это смешано потому, что я попробовал использовать `combine` из flow, но этот подход ждет пока все флоу дадут значение, а мне нужно их обьединить так, чтоб тригер происходил вне зависимости от того какой флоу обновляется.

Comment: Snapshot.withMutableSnapshot то пробовали использовать? А combine будет ждать только первые значения, но так как у вас в примере уже есть начальные значения "", то он должен тригернуться сразу и дальше тригериться на изменения в любом флоу